# How to make elements of a page stay while the rest of the page is refreshing / changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Example, on Facebook if you are chatting to friends and go to other pages the chat bar always stays on your screen without refreshing itself,

So I would like to know how to keep elements on a page whilst going to other pages

Comment: look into Single Page App development (SPA)... Angular, Reactjs, etc..

Comment: You use AJAX if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for *single page applications*.

There're many frameworks out there to develop SPA-style web apps:

- [Angular + UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).
- [Angular + newNgRoute](https://github.com/angular/router).
- [Aurelia.](http://aurelia.io/)
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

You should start learning one. An SPA can be done using vanilla JavaScript, but it would be re-inventing the wheel (well, unless you find a better wheel yourself...).

Probably both Angular combinations will be easier to learn since there's a huge community both developing and using them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because Facebook doesn't actually change the page. It fetches the page's content via a GET request and replaces the current page's content in the necessary areas and updates the browser's URL bar. If you want to achieve something like this, try using client-side frameworks such as AngularJS or Backbone.js (SPA).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, those pages use an asynchronus call to any code behind engine, either, java servlet, .net or php

You have to fire a Ajax call, maybe using Jquery, here is the documentation:

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Or if you are using .net you can use UpdatePanel.

With this call you send/receive data from the server, without leaving or refreshing the page, then with the response you can modify the current HTML element using any technique, like pure javascript, Jquery, angular or any other javascript framework, for a practical solution, you can add some more information to the question, like which technology are you using or some code that you already started.